# how to print data of a specific user using .loc function in dataframe with the help of index

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, series

I have created a dataframe

```
tmp = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(all_pred)
tmp_transpose = tmp.transpose()

tmp_transpose.head(3)
```

then I labled index as userId

```
tmp_transpose = tmp_transpose.rename_axis('userId')
tmp_transpose
```

I want to get data of one user thus I am getting an error

```
result=tmp_transpose.loc[196]
```

[image: Error]

Comment: always put code, data and error message as text, not image

Answer (score 0):

it seems your index is string `"196"`, not number `196`

```
result = tmp_transpose.loc["196"]
```

---

Minimal working example

```
import pandas as pd

#tmp = pd.DataFrame({'192': [1,2,3], '196': [1,2,3]})
tmp = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'192': [1,2,3], '196': [1,2,3]})
tmp_transpose = tmp.transpose()

#print(tmp_transpose.head(3))

tmp_transpose = tmp_transpose.rename_axis('userId')
#print(tmp_transpose)

print(tmp_transpose.loc['196'])  # OK
print(tmp_transpose.loc[196])    # error
```